# Unable to install msodbcsql17 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sql, mssql

I installed the sqlserver based on the [Microsoft Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017).
The following commands are executed correctly.

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list)"

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server

sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup

systemctl status mssql-server
```

[image: status of sql server]

But when I try to install the SQL Server command-line tools,the following error occurs.

```
sudo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-tools : Depends: msodbcsql17 (>= 17.3.0.0) but it is not going 
 to be installed
           Depends: msodbcsql17 (< 17.4.0.0) but it is not going to be 
  installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My operation system is Linux Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After searching around, I have found the requested package, it is located on [Microsoft Ubuntu 18.04 repository](https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list), in order to install the package you have to add the repo first.

This will install `msodbcsql17` that correspond to Ubuntu 18.04, open up terminal and run:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install msodbcsql17
```

Here is an update for `20.04`:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
```

Comment: Thanks you made my day :)

Comment: What a hero, everywhere else was out of date, this works as of july 2019

Comment: It does not work for me maybe package outdated.

Comment: "msodbcsql17 : Depends: unixodbc (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed" :(

Comment: bingo! take a [grand] bow . I updated yours for `20.04`: see below

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue but above solutions didn't workout for me. So here's how I solved this problem.

```
sudo apt-get install -y libodbc1
sudo apt update
sudo apt install unixodbc
```

Following commands from [microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu17)

```
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
```

Comment: This worked for me :)

Comment: Thanks! It works :)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem but not same. In my case error was

```
can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1' : file not found
```

I was uninstalling `msodbc` and then reinstalling it. 
After some research, I needed to uninstall `msodbc17`, and then do re-install.

```
sudo apt-get remove msodbcsql17
sudo apt-get install msodbcsql17 -y
```

Answer (score 0):

It was not enough in my case, and I was made to execute the following commands: 
`sudo apt install libodbc1
sudo apt install unixodbc`

Answer (score 0):

Update for `20.04` from the accepted answer

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
apt update
$APT msodbcsql17
```